# XMPP for LAN based multiuser game

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, xmpp

My question is about XMPP protocol; which is considered to be use for real-time scenarios,

is it that real-time which is usually in context of multiuser games?,

can somebody please tell,

How or whether it's fits into the context the real-time multi-user games like the conventional TCP and UDP protocol or

is it totally different beast,

in which context it fits for games? and which kind of games, it supposes to support well

Answer (score 0):

The XMPP protocol doesn't have anything to do with game servers. XMPP is a de-centralized chat protocol in which everyone can set up their own server. Of course you could synchronize your real time multi user game using messaged parsed from this chat system, but that would incur a lot of overhead (since XMPP uses long XML messages that are usually not encoded*.

A better/more usual way of doing communication in games is by building your own binary format that stores game state changes and sending this to a server using an UDP socket (be careful to time stamp your messages so that you can drop late messages, also incorporate in your design that some messages might get dropped). The server should check if the state change is valid and then redistribute it to the other clients. This gives you a low overhead protocol, but UDP does not guarantee ordering and delivery so for critical, but infrequent, messages you should use a second socket that sends messages over TCP (for example chat messages).

Now this might seems like an awful lot of work, but there are quite some code samples, and even packages for JAVA and other languages that have this server/client architecture set up for you, so you only have to send the messages.

*there are some XMPP extensions which compress/encode messages

Comment: Well I wouldn't but you could. From the XMPP website: "The Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is an open technology for ... voice and video calls ... "

Comment: so you meant all the XML based methods used for sending the data in case of multiuser real-time games are not eligible to use.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your latency and throughput requirements Xmpp may or may not be useful. If you were to write an internet distributed game, with social aspects and low content updates (say farmville) Xmpp would be useful, since it allows for easy scaling of many simulatenous users, tracking their online status, direct messaging between the users and the game components, etc.

For something fast paced, the overhead of the protocol likely makes unsuitable.

In the context of tcp/udp, xmpp is an xml stream protocol on top of tcp with centralized, but federated servers.